# Solr Boost on non-query term

Tags: solr, edismax

All my results are of type "active, inactive, historical" - this is a field indexed by Solr.

I want my results to be returned with a boost to **type="active"**.

I could do ordering which will suffice, but its not great.

So, when a user searches for a term "sick", they get the most relevant results to sick, but with a higher boost for documents where its active.

Not just a sorted result set!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [edismax parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ) and the following boost query `bq` paramter to get your desired results to be boosted to the top...

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=sick&defType=edismax&bq=type:active^5.0
```

In this example you are adding a boost query to increase the relevancy of documents whose type is active.

Here are some more examples on the Solr Wiki [DisMaxQParserPlugin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#Examples) page.

Answer (score 3):

The above example will create an additive boost.
If you want an multiplicative boost for "type=active" you could add:

`&boost=if(termfreq(type,"active"),2,1)`

Which gives a factor 2 boost for "type=active"

Comment: This boost method is recommended in this great article describing the different boost methods: http://nolanlawson.com/2012/06/02/comparing-boost-methods-in-solr/